# Maven - Discover class type at compilation time

Tags: java, maven

Is there any way I can find out a class interface/parent at compilation time in order to have a list of specific types at end?

My inittial idea was to build my project using maven, specifing some types that I want to search durring compilation in order to save the class name in a file that will be used later.

Any idea on how to get that?

Comment: Can you more elaborate what the purpose of this is? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure @khmarbaise - We have a legacy system that need to know in advance the types from a loaded jar. Today we have a property file inside each module that contains such infromation, but it was created manually. If I can find out at compilation time a could generate this file automatically.